# How to get the console logs of VM embedded within a docker container via "docker logs"

Tags: docker, logging

I have a Freebsd guest VM running within a linux docker container.
How do I get the console logs of this VM to show up in "docker logs" please?
At this point, the docker logs only show the logs for the startup process within the container. Want to also show the VM serial console logs.

The qemu startup parameters are shown below. The telnet port of 8601 is the serial console for the VM. I also tried not passing that to qemu and it did not solve the docker log issue.
QEMU is started in daemonized mode.

/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 
-daemonize 
-name fbsdvm 
-machine pc-0.15,accel=kvm:tcg,usb=off 
-name fbsdvm \
-cpu SandyBridge,+erms,+smep,+fsgsbase,+pdpe1gb,+rdrand,+f16c,+osxsave,+dca,+pcid,+pdcm,+xtpr,+tm2,+est,+smx,+vmx,+ds_cpl,+monitor,+dtes64,+pbe,+tm,+ht,+ss,+acpi,+ds,+vme 
-m ${VFBSDMEM} 
-realtime mlock=on 
-smp ${NUM_VCPU},sockets=1 
-uuid 772495e6-8658-4306-ba5f-f59c15f42f59 
-smbios type=0,vendor=Juniper 
-smbios type=1,manufacturer=VAPP,product=${VCP_I2CID},version=0.1.0 
-no-user-config 
-nodefaults 
-rtc base=utc 
-no-shutdown 
-device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 
-drive file=${IMG},if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=qcow2,cache=none 
-device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-  disk0,bootindex=1 
-drive file=${HDD},if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk1,format=qcow2,cache=none 
-device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x8,drive=drive-virtio-disk1,id=virtio-disk1 
-drive file=${METAUSB},if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk2,format=qcow2,cache=none 
-device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x9,drive=drive-virtio-disk2,id=virtio-disk2 
-netdev bridge,br=br-ext,id=hostnet0 
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=${MAC},bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 
-netdev bridge,br=int,id=hostnet1 
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet1,id=net1,mac=02:00:00:00:00:04,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 
-chardev socket,id=charserial0,host=127.0.0.1,port=8601,telnet,server,nowait 
-device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 
-chardev socket,id=charmonitor,host=127.0.0.1,port=8701,server,nowait 
-mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=readline 
-vnc 127.0.0.1:0 
-vga cirrus 
-device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6

Thank you.

Comment: If you want the logs visible via `docker logs`, you would need to arrange for qemu to output the console logs on `stdout` or `stderr`.

Comment: Thanks larsks, after posting this, I experimented and got the guest VMs console logs to show up in docker logs, however, I also need telnet to the VM to work and with these changes below, it connects to it but no longer can get into the serial console of the VM. Do you know how to fix this? Here are the changes compared to the original qemu startup args:

Comment: added "-serial mon:stdio" , removed daemonize option as won't work with this serial mon option, removed -nodefaults.

Comment: BTW, it is telnet localhost 8601 which is for being able to login to the VM from the host side and this is what no longer works once I got docker logs to show the VM bootup logs, here is what is at the end of VM bootup logs, the ttyu0 is interesting, anyway to make use of this ttyu0 given qemu is running inside a container? FreeBSD/amd64 (cmx) (ttyu0)